# WPF Data Binding object properties to text box by object name?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Good Evening,

i have a simple Problem:

I know that I can bind objects in Context of Data like this:

```
//Class CustomObject with a Property named "Property" with value "obj1"
CustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject("obj1");
DataContext = obj1;
<TextBox Text="{Binding Property}"
```

This works. But what is when I ve more than one object of a 
class. I tried something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding obj1.Property}"
```

Unfortunatly it doesnt work. Know anyone how I can
bind by object Name?

Thanks.

Edit:
In C# its working with this Code:

```
CustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject("Test");
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Property");
myBinding.Source = obj1;
textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

So I tried the same in XAML, unfortunatly not sucessfully:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Property, Source=Obj1}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding Path=Obj1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Text="{Binding Property}"/>
```

In this example Obj1 would be a property of whatever window you are working programming. 
Obj2 would also be a property if you were planning on binding it to another textbox in the same window and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

You would create a view model class that holds the CustomObject instance as one it its properties.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public CustomObject Obj1 { get; set } 
    // declare other properties ...
}
```

Then assign an instance of the view model to the window's DataContext

```
var obj1 = new CustomObject("obj1");
var vm = new MyViewModel
{
    Obj1 = obj1
    // assign other properties ...
};
DataContext = vm;
```

Now bind to it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Obj1.Property}" />
```

Comment: I don't want to use the mvvm pattern. I edited the Question - maybe you know the way how to do it? Thanks

Comment: As there can only be one object in the Window's DataContext, you'll have to assign an instance of a class with such properties. Alternatively, you could assign a CustomObject to the TextBox's DataContext in code behind.